# How to avoid the MaskedTextBox PromptChar being removed, when its container modal Form is shown?

Tags: c#, winforms, maskedtextbox

Using VS 2015 and C#...

I have this simple modal `Form` with just a `MaskedTextBox` control on it.
Each time after the first that `ModalForm` is shown with `.ShowDialog()`, the `PromptChar` in the control is gone.

To reproduce this issue:

```
    public ModalForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        maskedTextBox1.Mask = "00/00/0000"; // happens with any
        maskedTextBox1.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.IncludeLiterals;
    }
```

Code for main `Form`:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private ModalForm modalForm = new ModalForm();

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            modalForm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
```

The control's prompt appears again when its content changes, but at first view isn't present.

Setting the `TextMaskFormat` property to `IncludePromptAndLiterals` could be a solution, but then, `.Text` has to be cleaned up.
Is there another way to handle this?. Has become necessary for me, that all `MaskedTextBox` controls must always show its default prompt.

Comment: Default prompt lost after dialog close? Does it shows the previous value that you enter? Do you want to see default prompt everytime after showdialog, even you close it with a value i.e = `11/11/1111`? If not, please put some screen shots of the control.

Comment: Prompt is lost when calling `.ShowDialog()` for second time and so on, values are kept.
You can reproduce this issue with the code above. E.g. if you enter `"2_/1_/_85_"`, then close the form and open it again, the control shows `"2 / 1/ 85"`. What I'd like is to keep the prompt char.

Comment: Setting `AllowPromptAsInput = false` works?

Comment: @Berkay That doesn't work either. It's strange, each time the prompt chars are gone, if the control gets focused and a value is typed, they suddenly reappear.

Comment: Why `.Text` has to be cleaned up if `TextMaskFormat` is `IncludePromptAndLiterals`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this on Form's `Shown` event,

```
private void ModalForm_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e){
            if (!maskedTextBox1.MaskCompleted) // if there is missing parts it will return false, every false means prompts need in control
            {
                string tempText = maskedTextBox1.MaskedTextProvider.ToDisplayString(); // get the last value with prompts
                maskedTextBox1.Text = "";
                maskedTextBox1.Text = tempText; // then set the last value.
            }
        }
```

Hope helps,